# How to fix ./configure in MSYS2?

Tags: windows, mingw, msys2

I'm trying to build [libxc-4.3.4](https://gitlab.com/libxc/libxc/-/releases) in an MSYS2 shell on Windows 10. I've installed the latest version of MSYS2 (msys2-x86_64-20220319.exe) and followed the installation instructions. I've installed build tools using

```
pacman -S --needed base-devel mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain autoconf
```

I've installed libxc dozens of time on Linux machines. The first step is

```
./configure --prefix /somewhere
```

But in MSYS2 I get

```
$ ./configure --prefix $PWD/../libxc
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Are you in the right directory? Can you confirm with `ls` that `configure` is there?

Comment: Maybe you've cloned the repo instead of downloading the tarball? Readme says only tarballs include `configure`, and otherwise you need to generate it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### MSYS2 prerequisites

First of all make sure MSYS2 has all programs that are needed.

In the MSYS2 shell first update the package manager information:

```sh
pacman -Syu --noconfirm
```

Then install the packages you need. I would recommend at least these:

```sh
pacman -S --noconfirm autoconf autoconf-archive automake make libtool pkg-config
```

### Project sources

Next you should make sure the folder you are in actually has a configure script:

```sh
ls -l configure
```

A lot of projects these days are switching to more efficient build systems like CMake or Meson.
I usually use the following command in the projects source folder to check for several build systems:

```sh
ls -ld configure* m4 CMakeLists.txt cmake Makefile GNUmakefile setup.py scons SConscript SConstruct meson.build meson_options.txt *.pro *.proj *.sln BUILD.gn .gn 2> /dev/null
```

### building libxc

For the libxc project I see there is a `CMakeLists.txt` file and also a `configure.ac` file.
So either you should look into using CMake or generate the `configure` file with:

```sh
touch README ChangeLog
autoreconf -f -i -I m4
```

I have just tried to build libxc in MSYS2 with CMake and Ninja and this worked:

```sh
# set the line below to the desired install location
INSTALLPREFIX=D:\Prog\changeme

# build static library
cmake -Wno-dev -GNinja -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=$INSTALLPREFIX -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF -DENABLE_PYTHON:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_TESTING:BOOL=OFF -S. -Bbuild_static &&
 ninja -Cbuild_static install/strip &&
 echo SUCCESS

# build shared library
cmake -Wno-dev -GNinja -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=$INSTALLPREFIX -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON -DENABLE_PYTHON:BOOL=OFF -DBUILD_TESTING:BOOL=OFF -S. -Bbuild_shared &&
 ninja -Cbuild_shared install/strip &&
 echo SUCCESS
```